# IIS Express stopped working after updating VS2012 SP1

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-8

Update Visual Studio 2012 and after it IIS Express gives an error: "Unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server", when I try to run an asp.net project. Before upgrading all worked fine.

/trace:error mode gave such log

```
Starting IIS Express ...
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 264312930
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 264312946
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 264312946
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 264312946
Start listenerChannel http:0
Failed to initialize site bindings
Error initializing ULATQ.  hr = 80070005
Terminating W3_SERVER object
InitComplete event signalled
Process Model Shutdown called
Unable to start iisexpress.
```

Looks like that I need to change config file, because of updating IIS Express, but I don't know how.

Comment: Hey Alex, I posted a very detailed question for a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762646/debugging-mvc-application-in-vs2012-attempts-to-start-iis-express-twice

Is this the same issue you're having?

Comment: I am certain this is a Visual Studio 2012 bug. I posted a similar, more detailed question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762646/ I have also filed a bug ticket with Microsoft here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/778864/ If you believe this is the same problem you are having, please go to the bug ticket and vote it up.

Comment: is it due to framework compatibility issue? because vs 2012 has 4.5 f you are using 4.0 as the applcation pool it will not work

Comment: @w.brian yes, I guess it's the same problem. Solved by reinstalling Visual Studio.