# II Express for DotNetNuke won't start

Tags: iis, cmd, dotnetnuke

I am trying to build a DotNetNuke skin and today it won't load pages. I've tracked down the problem to the fact that II Express don't start up.

[image: II Express CMD Error]

That's the error I am getting. I tried uninstalling and installing. I tried removing the config files in my documents files. Neither worked out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you recently upgraded Visual Studio?  Here is a similar issue.  Read the comments for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687836/iis-express-stopped-working-after-updating-vs2012-sp1

Comment: @DotNetNuclear No, it's weird. It was working just fine. Then a few weeks later I went to use it and it started doing this. I even tried uninstalling and installing again.